# Launching Android Market Main Page from an application

Tags: android, google-play, program-entry-point, launch

I'm trying to write a launcher-like application (I'm not planning to release it, it's just for me to use) but I don't seem to find any way to launch the Market.

All of the answers I've found actually perform a search on the Market (using a uri "market://") or even worse they run the Market on a specific app page, while I'm trying to show the main page of the Market, i.e. the page shown when you run it from the launcher.

I tried using just "market://" as a Uri, without query strings, but it doesn't work; I also tried to get exactly the same "signature" of the "start activity command" that appears in the LogCat when I run the Market from the Launcher (by manually editing component, flags and categories), but it still doesn't work.

Is there any way to get it to show the main page?
Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.vending", "com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```